# Formatting In C

Tags: c, clion, c11

I keep getting a formatting error and I am not sure of how adjust my code.

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp=fopen("food.txt","r");
    float costs_2018[10];
    float costs_2020[10];
    char* name[1000][10];
    char* quantity[1000][10];
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s",&name[0], &quantity[0], &costs_2018[0], &costs_2020[0]);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d%*s %f %f",&name[i],&quantity[i],&costs_2018[i],&costs_2020[i]);
    }
    printf("total cost in 2018 is = %f",calculate_total_cost(costs_2018));
    printf("\ntotal cost in 2020 is = %f",calculate_total_cost(costs_2020));
    printf("\naverage cost in 2018 is = %f",calculate_total_average(costs_2018));
    printf("\naverage cost in 2020 is = %f",calculate_total_average(costs_2020));
    printf("\nDifference in total price between 2018 and 2020 is = %f",calculate_total_cost(costs_2018)-calculate_total_cost(costs_2020));
    printf("\nDifference in average price between 2018 and 2020 is = %f",calculate_total_average(costs_2018)-calculate_total_average(costs_2020));
    return 0;
}
```

on both of my "fscanf" lines im getting a formatting error.
The first fscanf line name,quantity,costs_2018,costs2019 are underlined red.
The 2nd fscanf line just name and quantity are underlined red.

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with your code?

Comment: Why `fscanf` outside and inside the loop?

Comment: name and quantity **are arrays of pointers** to type char. What you probably want is a pointer that points to a 2-dimensional array of chars. In that case it is `char (*name)[1000][10];`

Comment: I don't think the extra code you just added to the question makes the question clearer. It was pretty clear already.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want 10 `char[1000]`'s for `name` and `quantity`.

Declare those like this:

```
char name[10][1000];
char quantity[10][1000];
```

Then passing the arguments to `scanf` should be done like this:

```
if(fscanf(fp,"%999s %999s %f %f", name[i], quantity[i],
                                  &costs_2018[i], &costs_2020[i]) == 4)
{
    /* success */
} else {
    /* failure */
}
```

All arrays (like the `char[1000]` array at `name[i]`) decay into pointers when passed as arguments to functions which is why `&name[i]` should not be used.

Comment: ... and check the return value from `fscanf`

Comment: @EdHeal Indeed. Added check.

Comment: fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s",&name[0], &quantity[0], &costs_2018[0], &costs_2020[0]); could u share how I should fix this line so that both my cost fields would be accepted ?

Comment: @AB_12 It's exactly the same as the `fscanf` line in the answer but with `i` changed to `0`. I wonder why you want that line though? You'll overwrite the first entry in your arrays the first thing that happens in the loop.

Comment: @AB_12 Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

`char* name[1000][10];` is a 1000x10 array of (uninitialised) char pointers. What you probably mean is `char name[10][1000]` - an array of 10 strings with up to 1000 chars each. Char arrays are by nature pointers. There's no need to put `&` there. So right line is `fscanf(fp,"%s ...", name[0], ...)`.

Plus, line `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s",&name[0], &quantity[0], &costs_2018[0], &costs_2020[0]);` specifies string arguments for all parameters, but the two cost fields are floats.

Comment: how would i specify float arguments for the two cost fields ? or would it be better to just change the cost fields to a string argument

Comment: Floats are `%f`. A C++ reference or a short internet search for "printf format specifiers" gives extensive lists of all available specifiers.